# Fundamental matrix of a particular system

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, dynamical-systems, fundamental-solution

I'm interested of finding a closed formula for the fundamental matrix to the system
$$\eqalign{
  & y'(t) = a(t)z(t)  \cr 
  & z'(t) = \delta a(t)y(t) \cr} $$
$$(y(0),z(0)) = ({y_0},{z_0})$$
where $\delta$ is some constant and $a$ is a regular function. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A(t)=\int_0^ta(s)\,ds$. The matrices
$$
\begin{pmatrix}0 & a\\ \delta\,a & 0\end{pmatrix}\text{ and }
\begin{pmatrix}0 & A\\ \delta\,A & 0\end{pmatrix}
$$
commute. The fundamental matrix is then
$$
\exp\left(\begin{pmatrix}0 & A\\ \delta\,A & 0\end{pmatrix}\right)\ .
$$
If $\delta=\mu^2>0$, this is
$$
\begin{pmatrix}\cosh(\mu\,A) & \dfrac{\sinh(\mu\,A)}{\mu}\\ \mu\sinh(\mu\,A) & \cosh(\mu\,A)\end{pmatrix}\ .
$$
If $\delta=-\mu^2<0$, then it is
$$
\begin{pmatrix}\cos(\mu\,A) & \dfrac{\sin(\mu\,A)}{\mu}\\ -\mu\sin(\mu\,A) & \cos(\mu\,A)\end{pmatrix}\ .
$$

Comment: Thank you sir .

Answer (score 1):

Note, that the system has an invariant. The invariant is given by

$$\Phi(y,z) = \delta\cdot y^2-z^2=\text{const.}$$

You can use this to reduce the system to a scalar differential equation. If you have found the solution it should not be a problem to derive the fundamental matrix of this system.

Comment: Thank you for replying sir.